# Run into error “empty beginning of file” when read.table in R with 5 or more first empty lines

Tags: r, read.table

I'm trying to open a *.txt file which begins with 'n' empty lines, and I want empty lines to be considered as `NA`.

I'm using the `read.table()` function and `blank.lines.skip = FALSE` argument.
If the number of empty lines is less than 5, the file opens correctly with the proper number of NA lines, but if the file has 5 or more empty lines then I get the following error: `empty beginning of file`.

How can I allow my file to have as much empty lines as it wants and get the proper number of `NA` lines?

I would greatly appreciate any help and advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PavoDive has mentioned, the number **5** is hard-coded into the definition of the base R function `read.table`. If you really want to read in the blank rows, you'll need to make a temporary version of the function that uses a different value.

Here's one way to do it. Type `fix(read.table)` into the console. In RStudio this opens up another window which shows you the code behind `read.table`, and allows you to make changes. Change the **5** in line 34 to a number greater than the number of leading blank rows in your file. For example, I changed it to **6**:

[image: screenshot of Edit window]

When you hit "Save", you'll see a temporary function named `read.table` in your current R environment. (If you delete that object, clear your environment, or restart your R session, that temporary modified version of read.table will disappear and you will be back to using the original base R version of `read.table` that has 5 in line 34.) Now try reading in your file. It should be able to read your file into a table with the proper number of leading blank rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for these very clear answers!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the expected behavior of the function:

if you just type `read.table` you'll see the code for the function. About the first quarter of the total length you'll find that **5** was (somewhat arbitrarily) chosen as the threshold value for the number of lines to consider the file empty. I copy a fragment of the function:

```
pbEncoding <- if (encoding %in% c("", "bytes", "UTF-8")) 
        encoding
    else "bytes"
    numerals <- match.arg(numerals)
    if (skip > 0L) 
        readLines(file, skip)
    nlines <- n0lines <- if (nrows < 0L) 
        5
    else min(5L, (header + nrows))
    lines <- .External(C_readtablehead, file, nlines, comment.char, 
        blank.lines.skip, quote, sep, skipNul)
    if (encoding %in% c("UTF-8", "latin1")) 
        Encoding(lines) <- encoding
    nlines <- length(lines)
    if (!nlines) {
        if (missing(col.names)) 
            stop("no lines available in input")
        rlabp <- FALSE
        cols <- length(col.names)
```

and

```
else if (missing(col.names)) 
            col.names <- paste0("V", 1L:cols)
        if (length(col.names) + rlabp < cols) 
            stop("more columns than column names")
        if (fill && length(col.names) > cols) 
            cols <- length(col.names)
        if (!fill && cols > 0L && length(col.names) > cols) 
            stop("more column names than columns")
        if (cols == 0L) 
            stop("first five rows are empty: giving up")
    }
    if (check.names) 
        col.names <- make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE)
```

What's the important point here? To know that you can get to the code of most functions and understand why they behave the way they do.